# Apache works for IP but not for domain

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, domain

I've been running an apache server pretty smoothly for a while now by just using my web accessible IP address (xx.xx.xx.xx) in the apache virtual host setting as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"
 ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx
 <Directory /var/www/app>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have had no issues with this configuration. I then purchased a domain name, say foo.com, and have had no luck in trying to set it up with Apache - no matter the virtualhost config. When I replace the previous config with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"
 ServerName foo.com
 AliasName *.foo.com
 <Directory /var/www/app>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am then forwarded to the classic Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. I have tried other configs such as

```
<VirtualHost xx:xx:xx:xx:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"
 ServerName foo.com
 <Directory /var/www/app>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

with the same results. I have tried many other configs such as having both one for the IP and one for the domain (which then works for the IP address but gives ":( xx.xx.xx.xx connection refused" for when I type in foo.com). I have also tried utilizing the AliasName but to no avail.

Are there any troubleshooting tasks I am missing that could fix this or is there an obvious answer? I configured the A and AAAA records on my dns service (bluehost). It seems that the name is mapped to the correct ip and that the issue occurs when the connection reaches my server. While reaching the config page is nice, I'd love for the web app to run instead.

Thanks

edit:

I've also been using

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

directives in the .conf file.

The following is output from "apachectl -S"

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/config.conf:3
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost foo.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/config.conf:6)
                 wild alias *.foo.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

"

Below is output from access.log

```
yy.yy.yy.yy - - [01/Oct/2020:14:54:32 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 1237 "http://foo. com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
yy.yy.yy.yy - - [01/Oct/2020:14:54:33 -0400] "GET /index.php/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 302 442 "http://foo. com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
yy.yy.yy.yy - - [01/Oct/2020:14:54:33 -0400] "GET /index.php/user/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 200 9140 "http://foo. com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
```

And the following is the first two line in the access log out for xx.xx.xx.xx

```
yy.yy.yy.yy - - [01/Oct/2020:15:18:34 -0400] "GET /index.php/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 18928 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
yy.yy.yy.yy - - [01/Oct/2020:15:18:36 -0400] "GET /assets/eead54sf/js/test.js?v=28611 HTTP/1.1" 200 1063 "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Please also show the main-level configs, like the `NameVirtualHost` setting.

Comment: @tetech, ok I appended an edit.

Comment: @tetech Your two config are looking good. If you have setup one of those restart Apache2 and check if the vhost is listed in output of "apachectl -S" or "apache2ctl -S" if you are on debian.

Comment: @LukasRäpple, I appended the output to that command. I have the same output when having set my IP address as ServerName

Comment: @sadlyfe you could try disabling the two default vhost for 127.0.0.1 either by removing the config inside vhost.d/sites-enabled or with a2dissite

Comment: @LukasRäpple, sadly that still doesn't work. Does this sound like an Apache issue? I am sort of at a loss for how to troubleshoot this further

Comment: Are there requests in your access or error log if you access the website over the domain name? Is the Webserver directly accessed or through a reverse Proxy?

Comment: @LukasRäpple, I appended the access log output for requesting foo.com. I am also accessing the server directly through a cloud server instance. Based on the output it looks like Apache definitely handles the request but something after screws it up. Do you think this is an Apache issue or one with the application framework that I am using?

Comment: I also now get ":( xx.xx.xx.xx refused to connect" when I go to foo.com. If I type in xx.xx.xx.xx, then I get to the correct site..

Comment: I also compared the access log entries for when I enter xx.xx.xx.xx and it appears that as soon as the get request is received, it immediately prints the request with a 200. No 302 codes are printed.

Comment: I tried telnet foo.com and it appears that I had incorrectly set the IP address of the website.. so this was 100% my issue, although after fixing now I am able to connect through my phone but not through my computer.. this is tech :) @LukasRäpple, I appreciate your help, thanks!